# Build my own kernel on BeagleBone Black

Tags: operating-systems, kernel, embedded, beaglebone

I am trying to put an operating system like FreeRTOS onto the on-board storage on my Beaglebone Black via an SD card so that whenever I take the SD card out and restart, it will boot my new OS. I have already flashed a Debian image onto the on-board storage and my Beaglebone Black now boots with Debian. Can I do this same thing but with another OS that I want where it will completely erase the Debian image and boot completely from my new image?

I have seen some tutorials online but nothing seems to do exactly what I want. Can someone point me in the right direction as to where I might get started?

Comment: You seem to conflate the capabilities of a Linux distro with an embedded RTOS.  FreeRTOS is a minmal OS (i.e. just a kernel) intended for an embedded single application.  There certainly is no desktop GUI.  There's no CLI (e.g. a shell) unless you write one.  There are no userspace programs.   Without an application program, there's little sense in installing FreeRTOS on any SBC.

Comment: I'm not worried about having a GUI or anything else available to me. I have an RTOS with a shell included and am trying to get that onto my Beaglebone so that it can boot by itself. I want to overwrite the Debian image that is on the board now.